# enabling and disabling div element with javascript in Svelte

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

The following Svelte file produces a tree in which elements can be clicked.

### Current behaviour

The problem I have is that when I click on the div-element, the element is focused, but the previous elements are not focused.

### Expected behaviour

Only one div is active at the same time.

### Trials

I've tried several re-writings of this code, but it seems like I need to keep track of some kind of history, to undo focus.

```
<script lang="ts">
    import type { FrontendFile } from '$lib/front';
    export let content: FrontendFile;
    export let history: FrontendFile[];
    let text: string;
    function focusUnfocus() {
        for (let i=0; i++; i < history.length) {
            history[i].status.focused = false;
        }
        content.status.focused = !content.status.focused;
        history.push(content);

        if (content.status.focused) {
            text = 'font-black';
        } else {
            text = '';
        }
    }       


</script>
<div class="{text}" on:click={focusUnfocus}>
    {content.name}
</div>
...
{#each content.children as sub}
    <svelte:self bind:history bind:content={sub} />
{/each}
...
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are saying is not working. Your `i` variable in the `for` loop is never getting increased? `content` is never getting set? Getting JS errors? You need to explain in more details what you expected to happen and what happened instead. List Steps to Reproduce, Expected Behavior and Actual Behavior as separate sections with any error messages you may encounter. See  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing that out, my for loop was never run. It doesn't solve the problem, though.

Comment: A for loop is in the form `for (let i=0; i < history.length; i++ ) {`. You still haven't explained where content is being set. There's still not enough code for us to know what is happening. I think you don't need Svelte to figure out what your problem is. Try building a similar JS solution. It doesn't look like you have debugged and stepped through your application.

Comment: Stop using the word focused, focused means something specific, where the keyboard focus is. You probably mean dimmed and highlighted sections.

Comment: @JuanMendes, the content is a variable that bound recursively through the Svelte component. It is declared in the top-level index.svelte. Sorry, I found it sometimes hard to debug svelte code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following

```
<script lang="ts">
    import type { FrontendFile } from '$lib/front';

    export let content: FrontendFile;
    export let lastFocused: FrontendFile;

    function focusUnfocus() {
        if (lastFocused) {
            lastFocused.status.focused = false;
        }
        content.status.focused = true;
        lastFocused = content;
    }

    let text: string = '';
    $: if (content.status.focused) {
        text = 'font-black';
    } else {
        text = '';
    }

</script>
<div class=" {text}" on:click={focusUnfocus}>
    {content.name}
</div>

{#each content.children as sub}
    <svelte:self bind:lastFocused bind:content={sub} />
{/each}
```

I switched to 1-object history and  changed the binding in the top level `index.svelte` file as follows.

```
<script lang="ts">
    export let lastFocused;
</script>
...
{#each filesystems as system}
    <RenderTree {lastFocused} bind:content={system}
{/each}
...
```